# Set the same height 'li's with images

Tags: html, css

All my 'li' are set to 240w X 260h and inside I have a picture that can be up to 240w X 140H I want the images to be fit inside the div.photo however the picture' size but let's say that I changed my picture size to 200wX140 the layout is changing all the 'li' doesn't have the same height anymore

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/8t4yof6L/7/) : need to resize the 'result' frame

```
  <ul class="grid" masonry="true">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { name: nameFilter } | orderBy: order">
      <div class="photo text-center">
        <img src="{{item.picture}}" style="">
      </div>
    <div class="photo-description">
      <span>{{item.name}} </span><br/>
      <span>{{item.age}}</span><br/>
      <span class="label label-info">{{item.id}}</span>
    </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
```

css

```
.grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 240px;
    min-height: 260px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 260px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is make sure that displayed images are not higher then provided height. If they are,  than you need to scale down the image before displaying. I would leave the li tag as is but limit the img height attribute, something like:

```
<img src="http://www.tnetnoc.com//hotelimages/053/343053/2631759-Ramada-Hotel-and-Suites-Vienna-Meeting-Room-12.jpg"  height="140">
```

Comment: Thks Max; All my images can't be higher than 140px;  How can I set the same height for each 'li's like if it was in a table row?

Comment: Thanks it helps!  But I think I will rethink the architecture of my app cause the images have a bit of distortion but don't worry about that, I'll take it from there and: Thks You answered my question!